# User inputs in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to use highcharts (line chart) with user input data. Data is majorly in 2 range sliders and one tenure slider. 
x axis should have years from current_year to current_year + tenure, y axis should have data from two range sliders plotted in power of two first input (eg. data is 5 then 2*5, 2*2*5 and so on till tenure).

I am just starting with highcharts. Can you help me out on this?

Example:
Now these are investment, Tenure and debt ROI

So, you may consider this as the customer who is investing  for duration of  and expect returns of  percent.

Now your x axis which is increasing tenure from 0 to tenure (i.e. 0,1,2,3,... tenure).
Your y axis is amount (i.e. increased investment)
to calculate increased investment you may use compound interest formula i.e.
Compound interest = P(1+R)^N (P = investment amount, R is debt ROI, and N is Tenure)

So you will get Compound interest values (which are equal to number of tenures)

Example: if investment is Rs. 1000
Tenure is 5 years
Debt ROI is 7%

Tenure (or N)-  Compound Interest
1-  1070,
2-  1144.9,
3-  1310.7,
4-  1605.7,
5-  2104.8,

You need to plot: on x axis tenure, on y axis amount and points as compound interest.

[image]

Comment: As I can see this is a simple spline chart. So you have two inputs and your data is calculated based on them? The main issue with `highcharts` is how to update it each time user makes a change?

Comment: @WojciechChmiel But it is possible, please check this implementation: https://www.calculator.net/auto-loan-calculator.html?cloanamount=34000&cmonthlypay=380&cloanterm=60&cinterestrate=4.5&cdownpayment=5000&ctradeinvalue=0&cstate=&csaletax=7&ctitlereg=300&printit=0&ctype=standard&x=50&y=39#autoloanresult

Comment: Yes, it is definitely possible, yet what is your issue with highcharts to do it?

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you elaborate?

Comment: What you have presented on the attached image is a simple spline chart: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/we985knv/. And the implementation is simple line and pie charts: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic, https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic. So my question is what have you tried so far and what is your issue to do it?

Comment: I tried this, https://jsfiddle.net/nathandrake/n0ybuwm2/33/
but it doesnt works when range is changed with the range sliders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you have to add event listeners on range selectors to trigger a change and inside a callback function compute new data:

```
var pmtRange = document.getElementById('investment');
pmtRange.addEventListener('change', ...some function here);
```

Secondly, use `series.setData()` method to update the chart with newly calculated data:

```
chart.series[0].setData(ranges);
```

**Code:**

```js
var pmtRange = document.getElementById('investment'),
  tenureRange = document.getElementById('tenure'),
  roiRange = document.getElementById('roi'),
  chart;

function setData(chart) {
  var pmt = +pmtRange.value,
    tenure = +tenureRange.value,
    roi = +roiRange.value,
    ranges = [],
    monthlyRate = roi / 100 / 12,
    numMonths = tenure * 12;

  ranges[0] = pmt;

  for (var i = 1; i <= numMonths; i++) {
    ranges[i] = Math.round(
      (ranges[i - 1] * (Math.pow(1 + monthlyRate, i))),
      0
    );
  }

  chart.series[0].setData(ranges);
}

chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var chart = this;

        setData(chart);
      }
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      pointStart: 2011
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Installation',
    data: []
  }],
  responsive: {
    rules: [{
      condition: {
        maxWidth: 500
      },
      chartOptions: {
        legend: {
          layout: 'horizontal',
          align: 'center',
          verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
      }
    }]
  }
});

pmtRange.addEventListener('change', setData.bind(null, chart));
tenureRange.addEventListener('change', setData.bind(null, chart));
roiRange.addEventListener('change', setData.bind(null, chart));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<div class="range-slider">
  <input id="investment" type="range" value="1000" min="1000" max="30000" step="1000">
  <input id="tenure" type="range" value="5" min="1" max="20" step="1">
  <input id="roi" type="range" value="1" min="1" max="15" step="1">
</div>
```

**Demo:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/avru5y8x/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load